# Android text alignment in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, text-alignment

I have GridView with 4 TextView and I'm using SimpleAdapter to work with it. 
That's xml code for TextView:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:gravity="top"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
android:textSize="12sp"
```

But when I'm trying to set text to one of those TextView's, alignment doesn't work properly:

[image: GridView]

I.e. text position in TextView depends on TextView's index in the row of GridView.
So what is the reason of this strange behaviour?

UPD: 
This is the code of activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".WordMakerGameActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/pult"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/pult_image"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="99dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/last_letters_readed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/words_composed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/wrong_words_composed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/points"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/wordMakerGameGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" >

</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStopWordMakerGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/button_red"
    android:onClick="onStopWordMakerGame"
    android:text="@string/stop_game"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

And this is the code of layout that I use in my adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text_view3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text_view4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text_view5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="top"   
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you want to align the TextView, all of them must be aligned in top? **Could you please post the complete layout xml code?**

Comment: Try to remove this android:textAlignment="gravity" properties from your TextView.

Comment: @rogcg This is the code of activity layout:
http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?kxoo66h98viz
And this is the code of layout that I use in my adapter:
http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?b69szwfczkpy

Comment: @Haresh I tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: @floyd post the code as an update to your question please.